# How to dynamically refresh DataGrid from TreeView

Tags: wpf, sql-server

I have two columns: left containing 2 level TreeView Supplier/Category and the right containing DataGrid with products. I want to click on TreeView hierarchy (Supplier or Category) and the DataGrid should get refreshed based on what supplier or category was selected, in other words should display only products that belong to a selected supplier or category.
The code looks like that:

```
<Window x:Class="Replen.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Replen"
    Title="North Reports" Height="550" Width="1180">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider IsAsynchronous="True" x:Key="productNorthProvider" ObjectType="    {x:Type local:ProductNorthDB}" MethodName="GetProductNorthList">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:String>1</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>  
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="220" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ShowsPreview="True"
              Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="LightSteelBlue" />
    <GridSplitter VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ShowsPreview="True"
              Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Height="5" Background="LightSteelBlue"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Padding="0" Margin="0" Background="LightSteelBlue" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <TreeView Name="treeSuppliersCategories" Margin="5, 5, 0, 5" FontSize="12" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SupplierCategoryNorth}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SupplierNorthName}" Padding="2"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <TextBlock Name="categoryCode" VerticalAlignment="Center">            
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0}  {1}">
                                        <Binding Path="CategoryNorthCode" />
                                        <Binding Path="CategoryNorthName"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Border>        
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Padding="0" Margin="0" Background="LightSteelBlue">
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="gridProductsNorth" Margin="0, 5, 5, 0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource productNorthProvider}}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Width="60"  Binding="{Binding Path=ProductNorthCode}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" Width="160"  Binding="{Binding Path=ProductNorthName}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier" Width="60"  Binding="{Binding Path=SupplierNorthCode}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier Name" Width="160"  Binding="{Binding Path=SupplierNorthName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Width="60"  Binding="{Binding Path=CategoryNorthCode}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category Name" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding Path=CategoryNorthName}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="70"  Binding="{Binding Path=UnitPrice}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="In Stock" Width="70"  Binding="{Binding Path=UnitsInStock}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="On Order" Width="70"  Binding="{Binding Path=UnitsOnOrder}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>}
```

The data comes from a SQL server database. I would appreciate your help.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to directly bind a Model to the View at the moment.

You should investigate the MVVM Pattern.

When your selected item in the Treeview changes, you can directly change
the datagrid (i.e. provide other data for it)

MVVM decouples you view from your model:

Model <--> ViewModel <--> View

Selection changed in view, the ViewModel gets a notification (SelectedItem changed),
the ViewModel can then update the View with fresh data from the Model. In your case
there will be changed products in the datagrid by changing the ViewModel for the grid.

Here is an excellent video tutorial on MVVM:
[Jason Dollinger on MVVM](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650)

The sourcecode he develops in this tutorial is also available:
[Source code on Lab49](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2689)

Comment: Thanks Mare Infinitus for suggesting MVVM. I will obviously look into it in the future. Is there any other solution I can apply to my current case? Even as you suggesting MVVM would be probably better in this situation I believe that there is also another way to handle this.

Comment: Of couse there is more than one way to tackle this. MVVM is for me just the fastest and most maintainable way.